# Do not call Spring Security pre-authentication filter for specific URL and HTTP method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a custom pre-authentication filter which basically validates and creates a token.

I just want to call this pre-authentication filter only for secured APIs.

For example, I have these two APIs:

- `GET /api/products` (not secure)
- `POST /api/products` (secure)

When I use:

```xml
<http pattern="/api/products" security="none"/>
```

My pre-authentication filter is not called, but doing this I turn both APIs unsecure, because both have the same pattern `/api/products`.

I want to get my pre-authentication filter called **only** for my secure API, which is `POST /api/products`.

The question is: how to tell `security="none"` to differentiate HTTP methods (`GET` and `POST`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html) like [`AntPathRequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/AntPathRequestMatcher.html) and add the reference, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-http-attributes):

> **request-matcher-ref** A reference to a bean that implements `RequestMatcher` that will determine if this `FilterChain` should be used. This is a more powerful alternative to pattern.

Your modified configuration:

```xml
<http request-matcher-ref="myMatcher"/>

<b:bean id="myMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
    <b:constructor-arg value="/api/products"/>
    <b:constructor-arg value="POST"/>
</b:bean>
```